# Infer return type of function based on type guard

Tags: typescript

I have the following definition:

```js
function foo(arg: number[] | number) {
    if (Array.isArray(arg)) {
        return [1]
    }

    return 0
}
```

I would expect typescript to figure out automatically what the return type is. Because of the type guard `isArray()` it knows if arg is an Array and can show the return type as `number[]`. However, using `foo(...)` shows its return value as `number[] | 0` even when passing an array.

```js
  foo([]).push() // error because push doesnt exist on type 0
```

Is this a design limitation, a bug, just not implemented yet, or some other issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't point to something definitively saying it's a design limitation, but I've seen experts like [jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz) and [Titian Cernicova-Dragomir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125734/titian-cernicova-dragomir) citing various places where type inference is limited sometimes not because it couldn't do what we want, but because it would be too costly to do it (in terms of runtime cost or code complexity in the compiler). I suspect this fits into that category.

You probably know this, but for your specific example, you can use overloads to get the result you want:

```js
function foo(arg: number[]): number[];
function foo(arg: number): number;
function foo(arg: number[] | number) {
    if (Array.isArray(arg)) {
        return arg.map(v => v * 2);
    }
    
    return arg * 2;
}
foo([]).push(10);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUBDATgcwFyJggC2ARgKZYDaAugJQFFmW0DcAUKJLAsqprkYkKWBoWGUOXaPCQp02fOObUaiAD7KRdRAG92iQ4hjBEaAIJYsGAJ4A6GAGdL1mwJx0d+oz8RZyUCBYSIp2xBgADmgAbogAvAB8iLEAVIgATHQcPgC+7AZG-oHBiIqIaekcefJotHR2ESCOABZoAIwADFlAA)

Comment: Yes I know but how cool would it be if you wouldn't need to define all that overloads...

Comment: GitHub issue: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40802

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads).

Using overloading as followed would solve your problem:

```js
function foo(arg1: number[]): number[];
function foo(arg1: number): 0;
function foo(arg1: any){
    if(Array.isArray(arg1)){
        return [0]
    }

    return 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative are [Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html):

```
function foo<T extends number[] | number>(arg:T):T {
    if (Array.isArray(arg)) { return [1] as T }
    return 0 as T
}

foo([] as number[]).push(10) // works
foo(42).push(10) // error as expected
```

The consumer of `foo` gets perfect types. Inside we use a type assertion, as the `return`ed values are not [sound](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html). The shape of `T` is specified by the caller, so we cannot know, what exactly it is.

Imagine, the club of number `42` fetishists owns `foo` - all other numbers are mehh... :)

Then something like

```
function foo<T extends number[] | number>(arg:T):T {
    if (Array.isArray(arg)) { return [1]}
    return 1
}
foo(42); // T instantiated as 42
```

clearly wouldn't be tolerated.

While the example is contrived - the club sounds neat though -, you probably get the point, why first example needs to be [type asserted](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions).

A more realistic, sound sample:

```
function ensureDefined<T extends number[] | number>(initializer: () => T, arg?: T): T {
    if (arg === undefined || Array.isArray(arg) && arg.length === 0) {
        return initializer()
    } else return arg
}

ensureDefined(() => [42], [] as number[]).push(10) // works
ensureDefined(()=> 42, undefined) // error as expected
```

[Here is a Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcA8AVRBTAHlbMAEwGdEwQBbAI2wCcBtAXUQB9yra6A%20ACgEM6AcwBcGAJRjEAbwBQiBYhjBEvAIJ06-AJ4A6GCQ1btA4ePEzEdbFBB0kDAIwt%20ZLAF95i67fuIADIiuiBiynrIocLzMQWQUNPTM4roADiAkABa8jv4WAPR5iADucHQA1iQRqLwALABMyWmZ2bmIBTiapbE4uCnY0NhEssOgkLAIOGAkdtgAItjAMGCDmD0ExHGciSzs8Vx8SzCw-AA2MABe9CKqFgC83CEANEHCAPzXEh8yXgrKqoJCRC3YGIcBEBZLQZsdhGHT6QyaHSmIQWABkqJeQl0J0IQigGSBINackUpKsNjsSEOxzOlzovHEP0Q7hwJxI2HJviQALCw0I02s80WyyIvAZQIeDHqTGeMWCe22jXSWRy%20UKJXKlX5MyFkNFDPuiHqzzBEJFao6dC6wTwfQGQyAA).